# I can't run .kv file in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy, vscode-debugger

I am trying to learn kivy on vscode but when I create the .kv file and write the code in it,  there is no run button to run the code, if I switch back to my python file the button returns but then leaves again when I switch to .kv file, is there a way I can activate a run button for the .kv file?

I was following a YouTube tutorial and I did exactly as the youtuber did the only difference is that he was using pycharm and I was using vscode.

Comment: Thank you, I tried those along with code runner(which brought back the run button) but it still didn't work, it says code language not supported or defined

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [kivy extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BattleBas.kivy-vscode) to obtain support for kivy.

However, you cannot execute a `.kv` file. Have a look at the [kivy Getting Started](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Here are a few things you can do to activate a run button for your .kv file in VS Code.**

1. Save your .kv file.
2. Make sure that your .kv file is in the same directory as your .py
   file.
3. Install the Kivy extension for VS Code. You can do this by opening
   the Extensions tab in VS Code and searching for "Kivy".
4. In the Kivy extension settings, make sure that the "Run Kivy .kv
   Files" option is enabled. You can do this by opening the Kivy
   extension settings and checking the box next to "Run Kivy .kv
   Files".
5. Click the run button in the toolbar for your .kv file.

If you are still having trouble, you can ask for help in the **Kivy community**.

Comment: Thank you, I tried these and it didn't work, I did get Kivy to work in Pycharm thou so I might start using that instead

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).